# Preventing empty spaces on even number of cells

Tags: css, css-grid

I am building a grid layout and I need some help. Here's a description of the requirements.

1. Each cell in the grid has a minimum, fixed size (120px).
2. There will always be an even number of cells.

I would like the grid to fill up all the empty spaces.

My current implementation works for small container sizes, but the row overflow does not work at bigger sizes.

```
// Cells cannot be smaller than this value.
$minimum-cell-width: 120px;

.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax($minimum-cell-width, 1fr));
  width: 600px;
}
```

This gives me a grid that has 4 cells on the first row, and 2 cells in the second row. I need to have 3 cells per row, to fill all the empty spaces.

I would rather not increase the `$minimum-cell-width` variable (though it does fix it).

See the following codepen for more code and detailed examples:

https://codepen.io/surjikal/pen/XxxgNx

Answer (score 0):

How are the grid items supposed to know how many items you want per row?

All they know is that they can't be smaller than 120px width, but are free to consume free space (in their track).

All the container knows is its width. It has no idea what the items are supposed to do. The items have no idea where you really want them to wrap, so they fall back to their relationship to the container, based on the rules you've set.

The layout works in your smaller containers because the width of those containers matches well with the min-width you've set on the tracks to limit the number of items per row to an equal number. But if you reduce the min-width from 120px to, let's say, 50px, you'll find the same problem you're having with the larger containers.

For your layout to work, you need to define the width of the container (as you've already done) *and* the widths of the items. (You can do this without changing the min width variable.)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr));
}

.container-widest {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 25%)); /* new */
  width: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.container-wide {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 200px));  /* new */
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.container-narrow {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.4);
}

.container-narrower {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.4);
}

/* style stuff */
html {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.cell {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 1;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>This should be 4 cells per row, to fill all blank spaces</p>
<div class="container container-widest">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>

<p>This should be 3 cells per row</p>
<div class="container container-wide">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
</div>

<p>This one works great</p>
<div class="container container-narrow">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
</div>

<p>This also works great!</p>
<div class="container container-narrower">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still need to look through your response, but to answer your first question.. In theory, the algo has the choice between packing 3 cells per row, or 4 + 2. Both solutions are acceptable based on the constraints in my original css (I guess 1 or 2 cells per row are also acceptable too..). I was hoping I could add an additional constraint that would cause the algo to prefer the 3 cell packing method. I don't know how many cells I will have in advance, only that they will be an even number.

Comment: The empty spaces represent unoccupied cells in existing tracks. What you're trying to accomplish won't work because you can't make a grid item intrude into another track without setting a command (unlike flexbox, where "track walls" don't exist). That's why a break point, where wrapping can occur, is important.

Comment: I can't get this to work with flex either I think, the second row gets stretched out. Looks like I need JS perhaps.

Comment: Yeah. With flex you'll face the same problem. Grid/Flex items wrap where the math tells them to. If your goal deviates from the mathematical calculation, you need to introduce another rule.